# Prevent MacOS (Monterey) from Always Turning Wi-Fi ON when Startup or Log in

Tags: macos, network, wifi, startup

I notice MacOS **always** turns **on** Wi-Fi at startup, without my authorization. I ticked the option to ask for my admin password when turning on/off Wi-Fi in the preference panel.  Obviously, this option is discarded or ignored at MacOS startup.

Is there a command line trick (obviously, it's not possible via GUI) to ask MacOS to **never** ensble Wi-Fi? I will never use Wi-Fi and would rather have it off.

Comment: Pure guess - it's probably part of the 'Find My' security protocol.

Comment: I don't like MacOS telling others in the network “Hello, I'm here…”

Comment: It's going to do that over Ethernet too. What's wrong with being known on a network? If you're not joined to it, there's not even any active connection, the Mac would just broadcast a random MAC address to gather awareness on unknown networks. Knowing exactly what it is you're scared of might give better answers, as this is starting to feel like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps creating a new "Location" called "Wired Only" and remove the WiFi option would do this.